# How do I list all docker images which have been pulled in?

Tags: docker

Is there more than one way to show "possible" docker container images, that is docker containers which have been downloaded through the `pull` command as:

```
docker ps -a
```

lists jetty twice:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
490e3d669259        jetty               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   22 hours ago        Exited (143) 21 hours ago                       quirky_antonelli
a44230a617e1        jetty               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   22 hours ago        Exited (143) 21 hours ago                       goofy_hamilton
```

and:

```
docker container ls
```

no dockers currently running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

In fact I used `pull` to download both the above Jetty and a hello world.  How do I list everthing which is now available?

Comment: You pull **images**, not containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have pulled are images not containers. You can also use `images` sub-command. It's like an alias to `docker image ls`.

```
$ docker images
debian           latest         ae8514941ea4     2 weeks ago         114MB
python           alpine         f8a57363ff96     2 weeks ago         80.3MB
```

To get a list of incremental images use `-a` flag:

```
$ docker images -a
```

Comment: hmm, I seem to get different results for `image` versus `images`..

Answer (score 3):

command:

```
docker image ls
```

shows desired output:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jetty               latest              5f997007f18d        4 days ago          522MB
hello-world         latest              bf756fb1ae65        7 months ago        13.3kB
```